# how to use nouislider after npm install in laravel7

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, nouislider

## I wan't to import nouslider to laravel7 :

#### so what I did so far :

1. `npm install nouislider`
2. in resources/js/bootstrap.js I added :

   `window.nouislider = require('nouislider');`
3. I run the comand :

   `npm run dev`
4. in public/js/script I added :

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [20, 80],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});
```

5.and in my view I have :

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="slider"></div>
 </div>
```

I got this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined

I don't  know what I have to do after that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by a two errors:

**Error 1**

```js
window.nouislider = require('nouislider');
```

Then to use it you do `nouislider.create(...` and not `noUiSlider.create(...`

**Error 2**

The `defer` attribute can also cause this (it's included by default with Laravel auth):

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

You can either remove the attribute or execute your code once the page loads using `window.onload()`

**Note**

Also note that you need to add the `nouislider` style sheet in your `app.scss` add:

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nouislider@14.6.0/distribute/nouislider.min.css")
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `npm run dev` after

Comment: thanks for help it works fine on chrome but not firefox I think there is a  bug of compatibility  in the nouislider library

Comment: I tested on Firefox and it worked fine. They also state in their website that Firefox is supported. Any errors you received?

Comment: my bad it's working fine. I think It was a cache problem; thanks a lot !!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.